# Filtro en Datatable Javascript

Tags: javascript

Estoy realizando un filtro a una tabla, pero solo filtra la información que se encuentra en la página 1 del datatable. Necesito que me filtre la información que se encuentra en todas las páginas que tiene el datatable.

El código que tengo es el siguiente:

```javascript
var txtX3 = document.getElementById("txtX3").value;
var x =  txtX3.substring(0,3);
          
$("#tblCoordenadas tr").filter(function() {
  $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(x) > -1)
});
```

Comment: Yay! Felicidades.

Comment: Supongo que debes capturar el evento que lanza la visualización de las siguientes páginas y aplicar el mismo código que ya tienes cuando se produzca.

Comment: O intentar usar los callbacks de datatable: https://datatables.net/reference/option/  (concretamente el createRow o el drawCallback podrian ayudarte en lo que pretendes)